# JQuery on() optimization

Tags: jquery

Would including a context for jQuery on({}) make it faster?

Example:

```
$('body').on({
    click: function()
    {
        // blah 
    }
},'.myClass');
```

vs

```
$('body').on({
    click: function()
    {
        // blah 
    }
},'.myClass','#myWrapper');
```

Comment: I don't think that's how `on` works. The third argument is supposed to be `data`, not "context", if I'm reading the docs correctly.

Comment: your context is in this case `body`. You can also do: `$('#myWrapper').on({ /* handlers */ }, '.myClass');`

Comment: If the context is `'#myWrapper'` make your code be `$("#myWrapper").on({}, ".myClass")`. You always want to bind your handler to the closest static ancestor element of your dynamic element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faster option will be

```
$('#myWrapper').on({
    click: function()
    {
        // blah 
    }
},'.myClass');
```

This will be faster than `$('body').on(...)` because, in this every click happening in the page will be evaluated against teh selector `'.myClass'` but when you use the above option only clicks happening inside `#myWrapper` will be evaluated

Comment: @user1083320 as long as the dynamic elemens are inside `#myWrapper`

Answer (score 0):

No, including a context for `on` is not faster then the `.click` and other events.

As on is used to add the events for those also which elements are created dynamically.
And on will search for all element from the beginning of body. and other events will bind on the page render so that will be faster.

`.on` is used when you are creating the elements dynamically and want to give some events on those elements.

**EDITED:**

The syntax of `.on` is not correct in your. It should be this:

```
$('body').on( "click", "#.myClass, #myWrapper", function(e) {
   //your code
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am creating the elements dynamically, and that is why I am using it.

Comment: @user1083320 ok, Then you can use this method. for make faster it. give the class or id name in place of `body`.